# Remove array elements that are too close to each other

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of float elements and I'm trying to remove elements that are close to each other.
I.e. if there are two elements less than 0.4 apart (e.g. 15.1 and 15.3), I want to remove the second one. The 0.4 should be the input parameter for the algorithm.

The array is already sorted in a specific order (not ascending/descending) and I need to preserve that order.

Comment: My advice would be: Please show what you have attempted...

Comment: Should the second element in a close pair be removed even if the first element is also a candidate for removal?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Ben, only the subsequent close elements should be removed, i.e. all except the 1st one. Think of it as data de-duplication. Only instead of removing the same values, we're removing values that are similar enough. Thanks.

Comment: Mitch, sure thing. So far I've tried using the Dictionary/Hashset to keep track of the values I've already visited but those structures seem to only look up values by the exact keys, not by similar ones.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you have { 15.1, 15.3, and 15.6 }, what gets removed?

Comment: Can the list contain duplicate values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an `ApproximateFloatComparer` class as follows:

```
public class ApproximateFloatComparer : IComparer<float>
{
    public float Range { get; set; }

    public ApproximateFloatComparer(float range)
    {
        this.Range = range;
    }

    public int Compare(float x, float y)
    {
        if (x - this.Range < y && x + this.Range > y)
            return 0;
        else return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Then create a method to deduplicate:

```
public static List<float> Deduplicate(List<float> floats, float range)
{
    var dedup = new List<float>();
    var comparer = new ApproximateFloatComparer(range);
    foreach (var @float in floats)
        if (!dedup.Any(f => comparer.Compare(f, @float) == 0))
            dedup.Add(@float);
    return dedup;
}
```

Then combine it all:

```
var floats = new List<float>() { 5, 8, 2, 13, 6, 9, 4, 3, 2.1f, 8.6f, 2.2f };
floats = Deduplicate(floats, 0.4f);
```

Answer (score 3):

Through a simple `while`, using `List<float>` instead of `array`, with an extension method:

```
public static void Deduplicate(this List<float> values, float delta, int decimals)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < values.Count)
    {
        float value = values[index];

        int i = index + 1;
        while (i < values.Count)
        {
            if (Math.Round(Math.Abs(value - values[i]), decimals) < delta)
                values.RemoveAt(i);
            else
                ++i;
        }
        ++index;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
List<float> values = new List<float> { 3.4f, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1.2f, 2.5f, 3.6f, 1 };
values.Deduplicate(0.4f, 5);//       { 3.4f, 1, 2,    4,       2.5f          }
values.Deduplicate(0.4f, 10);//      { 3.4f, 1, 2, 3, 4,       2.5f          }
```

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin. This is a great solution for in-place filtering.